# Why do small introduction Ethereum miners not exist, similar to Bitcoins Block Erupters?

Tags: mining, bitcoin

I was introduced to Bitcoin and crypto with Block Eruptors which were little miners which would not realistically earn you anything but were a big hit, is there a technical reason Etherum miners only exist in massive rigs?

I've had a hunt around for small miners but cannot seem to find anything similar to the Bitcoin equivalents.

Many thanks.

Comment: It depends on what do you mean by "small miners". There are people that mine using a single GPU connected to a mining pool. You could 'solo mine' running a full node.

Comment: Small similar to something like [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/ASICMINER-Block-Erupter-336MH-Generation/dp/B00CUJT7TO).

Comment: Ethereum PoW algorithm requires lots of memory (currently more than 4Gb), also the swith to PoS may have some influence. The smaller thing I saw is using raspberry pi for mining a testnet but it was experimental.

Comment: Yes, I did some more research and the switch to PoS was something I thought would have an effect. The information regarding the PoW algorithm and its requirement for large amounts of memory makes a lot of sense and clears things up, thanks!